# Get and check a value from JSON read in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, readfile

I'm trying to check if a user exists (registered on a json file).

Unfortunately I don't find a valid solution in all Stack Overflow that gives me a simple "true" in a callback.

The version closest to a solution

---

**Experiment V1 :**

```
let userExist;
function check(){
  console.log("CHECK!");
  return userExist = true;
}
// check(); if this, return true... obvious.


//// check if user exist

server.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8', (err, data) =>
{

  let json = JSON.parse(data),
      userlist = json.allusers;

  for (let key in userlist)
  {

    if ( userlist[key].email == req.body.user_email ) 
    {
      console.log("FINDED EQUAL");
      check(); // return undefined ???
    }

  }

});

console.log("userExist value : "+userExist);
```

differently formulated the debugs also appear, but "true" never returns.

note: **yes, JSON is read correctly. If everything works inside the readfile, you immediately notice the same emails.**

> ```
> output: "undefined"
> Log: total bypassed
> ```

---

**Experiment V2 :**

In this case (with asynchronous reading) it returns all the debugging (but the "true" remains undefined)

The problem with the asynchronous is that I have to wait for it to check to continue with the other functions.

```
  //// check if user exist

server.readFile(filepath, 'utf8', (err, data) =>
{

  let json = JSON.parse(data),
      userlist = json.allusers;

  for (let key in userlist)
  {

    if (/* json.allusers.hasOwnProperty(key) &&*/  userlist[key].email == req.body.user_email ) 
    {
      console.log("FINDED EQUAL");
      check();
    }

  }

});

var userExist;
function check(userExist){
  console.log("CHECK!");
  return userExist=true;
}

console.log("userExist value : "+userExist+"");
```

> ```
> server listening on: 8080
> userExist value : undefined
> CHECK!
> FINDED EQUAL
> ```

---

**Experiment V3 :**

after the various suggestions I come to a compromise by using the syntax for the async functions.

This allowed to reach an ordered code, but despite this it is not possible to wait for the results and export them out of the same function (this is because node itself is asynchronous! Therefore it has already gone on!)

using a "message" variable to check if it could return an object I did so:

```
//simple output tester
var message;

// create a promise
let loopusers = new Promise( (resolve)=>{

  server.readFile( filepath, 'utf8', 
  (err, data) => {

      let json = JSON.parse(data),
          userlist = json.allusers,
          findedequal;

      console.log("CHECK USERS IN DB...for "+userlist.length+" elements");

      // loop all items
      for (let key in userlist)
      {

        console.log("Analyzed key ::: "+key);
        if ( userlist[key].email == req.body.user_email ) 
        {

          console.log("CHECK : user isn't free");
          findedequal=true;
          resolve(true); // return the result of promise
        }

        else if(key >= userlist.length-1 && !findedequal )
        {
          console.log("CHECK : User is free ;)");
          resolve(false); // return the result of promise
        }

      }

      // call the action
      createuser();

    });


});

// when promise finished --> start action
async function createuser(message)
{

  let userExist = await loopusers;
  console.log("userExist: "+userExist);

  if(userExist)
  {
      message = { Server: "This user already exists, Try new e-mail..."};
  }

  else
  {
      message = { Server: "Registration user -> completed..."}; 
  }

  // return values
  return message;

};
```

It is also possible to use the classic syntax via "then". For exemple:

```
//simple output tester
var message;

// create a promise
let loopusers = new Promise( (resolve)=>{
    ...
});

loopusers.then( (response)=>{
  ...
})
```

Then I realized that it was easy to simplify even more by calling the functions directly from the initial one:

```
    var message;

// create a promise --> check json items
server.readFile( filepath, 'utf8', 
(err, data) => {

    let json = JSON.parse(data),
        userlist = json.allusers,
        findedequal;

    console.log("CHECK USERS IN DB...for "+userlist.length+" elements");

    for (let key in userlist)
    {

      console.log("Analyzed key ::: "+key);
      if ( userlist[key].email == req.body.user_email ) 
      {

        console.log("CHECK : user isn't free");
        findedequal=true;
        createuser(true); // call direct function whit params true

      }

      else if(key >= userlist.length-1 && !findedequal )
      {
        console.log("CHECK : User is free ;)");
        createuser(false); // call direct function whit params false

      }

    }

  });


// start action
function createuser(userExist) 
{

  if(userExist)
  {
      message = { Server: "This user already exists, Try new e-mail..."};
  }

  else
  {
      message = { Server: "Registration user -> completed!"}; 
  }

  // return values
  return message;

};
```

> debugging is taken and written
>
> the message is lost outside the aSync function

**Experiment V4 Final! :**

Finally, after many attempts the solution! (Yes... But know it's not Async)

If we allocate in a variable the reading becomes synchronous the whole model and we return to the simple one

```
    let message,
        file = server.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8'), // read sync
        json = JSON.parse(file),  // now parse file
        userlist = json.allusers,   // get your target container object
        userExist,
        findedequal;

   console.log("CHECK USERS IN DB...for "+userlist.length+" elements");

   for (let key in userlist)
   {

      console.log("Analyzed key ::: "+key);
      if ( userlist[key].email == req.body.user_email ) 
      {

          console.log("CHECK : finded equal value on key ["+key+"] - user isn't free");
          findedequal=true;
          userExist = true;

      }

      else if(key >= userlist.length-1 && !findedequal )
      {
          console.log("CHECK : User is free ;)");
          userExist = false;

      }

   }

   if(userExist)
   {
          console.log("└ EXIT TO CHECK --> Can't create user, function stop.");
          message = { Server: "This user already exists, Try new e-mail..."};
   }

   else
   {

          console.log("└ Exit to check --> New user registration ...");
          message = { Server: "Registration user -> completed!"}; 

   }

}

return message;
```

Now:

> ```
> It's all sync and all log is perfect
> all var is checked
> all return... return
> ```

---

** Final conclusions: **

Is it possible to retrieve an ASync variable in node?
As far as I understand so far ... no.

Node is async by its nature, therefore recovering information that is not saved and then recovered from a DB is left behind among the things to do, becoming unrecoverable if you use it as in this post.

However ... if the purpose is to make reading a file synchronous, the answer was simpler than expected.

---

A special thanks to: Barmar; Austin Leehealey; C.Gochev;

Comment: Are you getting the `CHECK!` log message?

Comment: Have you tried just to initialize `let userExists = false` and in the if to set it to true you don't need to return it from a function.

Comment: BTW, you can just use `userExist = userlist.find(user => user.email == req.body.user_email)`

Comment: Is this code inside an async function? Is the `console.log` at the end inside the same function?>

Comment: Then ...

A) in other forms it takes all the logs, in this one it specifically does not (I don't understand why)

B) yes, I tried to instantiate it, it always comes back undefined

C) should be synchronous because there is nothing Async set

I thank you so much for your replies to this hour and on this day, I did not expect them

Comment: @Barmar I did not know I could use a find, if I solve peremption also on that to learn, thanks.

ok I tried ... back undefined as always.

Comment: It just simplifies the loop, but it won't solve the problem.

Comment: yes, it's true, in fact I tried.

I do not understand why the cabbage value does not come back.

Beyond the fact that using a json for this is not correct (a database like mongo db would be appropriate), however I should be able to verify if the value exists or not for anything else! I'm really getting stupid

Comment: maybe do it without a callback something like `const f = fs.readFileSync(filepath);` then parse it and do the loop

Comment: @C.Gochev And I've already thought about it (however now I try again for the umpteenth time) but it goes back the whole function instead of the simple "true"

Comment: can you give more context why do you use `server.readFile` did you name the `fs` package server?

Comment: What is the console output of the synchronous version?

Comment: @C.Gochev I don't know if I understand correctly what you ask me ...

If you mean the name "server" it's just for beauty compared to "fs".

If, on the other hand, you are referring to the charge, unless I am doing a bullshit, I have loaded it:

server = require ('fs'),
      filepath = './service/data/datastore.users.json';

I could not give you more specifics so easily because I simply have this json file and this API that reads it and saves the new user. If you can explain yourself better I try to tell you more

Comment: @HereticMonkey is a simple "undefined", bypasses each log and returns instead of true "undefined"

Comment: @Barmar YOOOO thanks, I have a solution!
As you suggested at the beginning, everything is to tell him immediately with:
"const f = fs.readFileSync(filepath); " allocating the reading in memory immediately!

I was wrong to loop after that's why it got stuck!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling console.log("userExist value : "+userExist+""); 
too early.  At the moment that you call that line, userExist is not defined yet.  This is because the server.readFile() function requires a callback and that callback function is executed once it has read the file.  However, reading files often take time and so the program keeps going.  It executes console.log("userExist value : "+userExist+""); and then goes back to the callback function and defines userExist as true.

If you want more information on what callbacks are look at the link below.  Callbacks are a defining feature of Nodejs and understanding them is essential to any Node website.

https://medium.com/better-programming/callbacks-in-node-js-how-why-when-ac293f0403ca

Try something like this.

```
let userExist;
function check(){
  console.log("CHECK!");
  return userExist = true;
}
// check(); if this, return true... obvious.


//// check if user exist

server.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8', (err, data) =>
{

  let json = JSON.parse(data),
      userlist = json.allusers;

  for (let key in userlist)
  {

    if ( userlist[key].email == req.body.user_email ) 
    {
      console.log("FINDED EQUAL");
      check(); // return undefined ???
      console.log("userExist value : "+userExist);
    }

  }

});
```

Comment: wow, I didn't think it would happen in sync too!

I try to verify by putting a timeout

At that point I will have to better understand how to wait for him to finish reading everything, which I do not know currently.

in any case thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, inside the Read it works, but it doesn't come out in any case.

That was the problem.

Inside there is but outside it does not arrive

Not even with a wait timeout

Comment: Thank you for your help. After studying this, there is actually a method of washing inside the async. However, they were unable to work the other variables out of the latter thanks to its results.

In any case, experimentation has led me to valid compromises that have suggested, in the end, a solution the same: D